# How to create a label inside an <input> element and style it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder, textinput

I can make my label inside an input element (my "disappearing text"):

HTML

```
<input name="firstName" type="text" maxlength="40" value="Enter your first name"
 onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" 
 onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" />
```

Then style it so my disappearing text is faded (#333). And style it so when I start to input a value into the field the text is black (#000).

CSS

```css
input[type=text] {
    color: #333;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    color: #000;
}
```

It all works fine until you move onto the next input field.  Then the field you just entered a value in changes back to the `#333` color.  I can see why that happens, but can't quite get to how to keep the value black `#000` color if the input field has had a value put into it.

Thanks in advance for the assist and education!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work xbrowser using a combination of jQuery and the Modernizer library.

Requires the jQuery and Modernizer Libraries be on the site and properly referenced.

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){

$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur();
$('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
  })
});

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input name="firstName" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter your first name">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
color: #000;
}

input[type=text].placeholder {
color: #666;
}
```

SOURCE: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Answer (score 5):

### HTML5

HTML5 brings a handy attribute for the `<input>` tag called `placeholder` which enables native support of this functionality.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPr6m/)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
```

#### Support

All latest browsers support this, [IE9 and below don't however](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder).

#### `<label>`

Note that the [placeholder attribute is not a replacemenr for the `<label>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157867/placeholder-vs-label-for-input-in-html5) which every input should have, make sure you include a label for the `<input>` even if it's not visible to the user.

```
<label for="search">Search</label>
<input id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
```

The above `<label>` can be hidden so it's still available to assistive technologies like so:

```
label[for=search] {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
}
```

### Cross-browser solution

Here is a potential cross-browser solution, I've moved the code out of the tag and into script tags and then used the class `placeholder` to indicate when to fade the text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYGth/3/)

**HTML**

```
<input name="firstName" type="text" maxlength="40" value="Enter your first name" 
    class="placeholder" id="my-input" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text].placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

input.onfocus = function () {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue && this.className == 'placeholder') {
        this.value = '';
    }
    this.className = '';
};
input.onblur = function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.className = 'placeholder';
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
};
</script>
```

#### Apply to all `input[type=text]`

We can extend the above solution to apply to all `input[type=text]` by using `document.getElementsByTagName()`, looping through them and checking the `type` attribute with `element.getAttribute()`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3FhA/1/)

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].getAttribute('type') === 'text') {
        input[i].onfocus = inputOnfocus;
        input[i].onblur = inputOnblur;
    }
}
function inputOnfocus () {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue && this.className == 'placeholder') {
        this.value = '';
    }
    this.className = '';
}
function inputOnblur() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.className = 'placeholder';
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that only HTML5 though?  Need something more backwards compatible

Comment: Note that [`placeholder` is not a replacement for `label`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157867/placeholder-vs-label-for-input-in-html5).

Comment: Almost there :-)  The JS appears to only reference a specific input ID.  Need this to apply to all input[type=text] elements, not just a single one referenced by ID.  Thx.

Comment: Updated to apply to `input[type=text]`.