# Making multiple input fields in a webpage look like one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I created four text input fields in a single row in a HTML table. Like expected, they show as four separate boxes. I want to make them look like one long field with placehohlders at different positions to indicate the different values. I know that it might look like one field when I have removed the text box borders, but is there some other way?

```
<form>
<table>
 <tr>
 <input type="text" id="project" placeholder="project">
 <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="task">
 <input type="text" id="skill" placeholder="skill">
 <input type="text" id="phase" placeholder="phase">
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path there. Remove borders, wrap them in a `div` and give that a border. They'll look like one field.

Comment: Labels please! Give screenreader users a fighting chance (and, no, [`placeholder` is not a replacement for `label`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163993/557612).

Comment: @steveax I include screenreader-only labels using the `.sr-only` class (from Bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove default `margin`, display `input`s next to each over and style borders to look like on long `input` :

```
input{
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0;
    border-width: 1px 0 ; 
}
input:first-child{
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px; 
}
input:last-child{
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0; 
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97UcJ/1/)