# Login with username or email using node and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating a login page which should be logged in if we enter username or email and password. the backend(nodejs) is working but i'm having a problem with the frontend i did the username part but have no idea how to do the email. It would be good if someone would help me out. My code includes:

the backend:
server.js

```js
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
    const userInfo = req.body  
    if (req.body.username){
    Register.findOne(
      { username: userInfo.username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      } else {
        console.log(user)
        if (user !== null) {
          if (user.password === userInfo.password) {
              res.status(201).json({success: true, user: user, message: 'LOGGED_IN'})             
          } else {
            res.status(201).json({success: false, message:'WRONG_PASSWORD'})
          }
        }} else {
          res.status(201).json({success: false, message: 'NOT_FOUND'})
        }
      }
    })}
    else if(req.body.email){
      Register.findOne(
        { email: userInfo.email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
          console.log(user)
          if (user !== null) {
             if (user.password === userInfo.password) {
              res.status(201).json({success: true, user: user, message: 'LOGGED_IN'})             
          } else {
            res.status(201).json({success: false, message:'WRONG_PASSWORD'})
          }
        }} else {
          res.status(201).json({success: false, message: 'NOT_FOUND'})
        }
      }
    })}
  })
```

Comment: your only sending up username, so really you need to change the query, if that's sequelize, findOne has *or* functionality so you can match both username field and email, the rest is just duplication

Comment: Could u specify more, I'm sending both email and username and it depends on what the user is entering i tested the backend with postman and it's working the problem is in the frontend it's only working for the username, i was trying to do the same for the email but nothing was helping

Comment: I want to allow user to login with either username or mail in the frontend, not making him log in with only username or only email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to start off with informing you that you have multiple accessibility and also security problems. But first of all lets get it to work :)

When you only have one input field for username/email, you need to check one variable on the server, if its an email, search for the email. If it's not an email, check for the username.

```js
const isEmail = (str) => {
  // return true when str is an email
  // return false when str is not an email
};

app.post("/users/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  const callback = (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
      return;
    }

    if (user) {
      res.status(201).json({ success: true, message: "LOGGED_IN" });
    } else {
      res
        .status(201)
        .json({ success: false, message: "USER_AND_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG" });
    }
  };

  if (isEmail(username)) {
    Register.findOne({ email: username, password: password }, callback);
  } else {
    Register.findOne({ username: username, password: password }, callback);
  }
});
```

So, now for the anti-patterns inside your code.

- It's generally bad practice to give out the information of "User not found". This info can be used maliciously, as this gives other people the opportunity to check if an email is registered at your site or not. Therefor you should only give out the information of "user and or password are wrong", and not even give out the information if you have not found the given email address if it doesn't exist.
- The button that you're using for sending the form should be simply of `type="submit"` (which is the default). Then you should have an onSubmit listener on your form tag. This enables you to use html 5 validation that is only triggered upon submitting the form. By having the eventlistener on the button instead of the form you negate this effect.
- You should have labels for your input fields (and no, placeholders are not labels). Using placeholders as labels is w unfortunately wide spread anti-pattern. See this as additional infos [Placeholder VS Label for input in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157867/placeholder-vs-label-for-input-in-html5) (and there are many many posts about this)
- And please make sure your passwords are not cleartext inside your database

If you have any questions as to why, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Thank u for all that information, and it works.